# Parquet file logical type mapping

Tags: thrift, parquet

In parquet files, data is stored in a small number of primitive types. There is, however, the concept of higher-order logical types (aka converted types). For example, a DECIMAL(10,2) may be stored as a byte array of length 3, i.e., an integer where the division by 100 to fixed-precision decimal is defined by the schema.

My question is this: where is there a map from numerical logical type to identifiers such as DECIMAL, and how are they further specified?
As far as I understand, the schema thrift spec block looks like this:

  `thrift_spec = (0, type(I32), type_length(I32), 
    repetition_type(I32), name(string), 
    num_children(I32), converted_type(I32), ...
  )`

It is the meaning of the last variable I am after, and what further information may follow in the spec.

Comment: I had search thrift equivalent for "decimal" too, portability between languages is important. Without elegant solution I have select integer * 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief description is given here, so I was right about DECIMALs. How exactly the other are used remains somewhat opaque.

https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-format/blob/master/src/thrift/parquet.thrift#L65

Specifically, the scale to multiply by is 10**b where b is the next 32-bit integer in the spec block.

Comment: old but any idea how to print these out using parquet-tools?

Comment: I don't know what parquet-tools is, but since I wrote this answer, I assume I coded fastparquet to cope with this (it's been a while, however)